# Issue with AWS - Lambda python packaging

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-packaging

I get this error in the logs "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?". I'm trying to deploy python code in AWS Lambda and I downloaded lxml from https://github.com/JFox/aws-lambda-lxml . I made a zip with all libraries and the code. Still getting this error